# Asynchronous Request Appending to String in Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, coffeescript, promise

I am attempting to get the actual text from all of the stylesheets associated with the page. I can do this pretty well via something like

```
sheets = document.styleSheets
stylesheet_text = "<style type='text/css'>"
_.each(sheets, (sheet) ->
  if $(sheet).attr("href")
    $http.get($(sheet).attr("href"))
      .success (data) ->
        console.log data # Displays the text perfectly
        stylesheet_text += data # Never gets appended to.
      .error (data) ->
        console.log "error"
)
stylesheet_text += "</style>"
console.log stylesheet_text
```

The problem is that the final `console.log` doesn't display the correct data. Instead, I get back

`<style type='text/css'></style>`

After this, the `console.log data` fires and starts spitting out the text. Oh, an async issue! A promise should fix this, right?

```
getCSSFile = (href) ->
    def = $.Deferred()
    $http.get(href)
      .success (data) ->
        def.resolve(data)
    def.promise()



css = ->
    sheets = document.styleSheets
    stylesheet_text = "<style type='text/css'>"
    _.each(sheets, (sheet) ->
      if $(sheet).attr("href")
        getCSSFile($(sheet).attr("href")).then( (data) ->
          stylesheet_text += data
        )
    )
    stylesheet_text += "</style>"
    console.log stylesheet_text
    stylesheet_text
```

Well... not quite. That still didn't work. So, I decided to just go with a route that I thought I *knew* would work.

```
ss = ->
    sheets = document.styleSheets
    stylesheet_text = "<style type='text/css'>"
    _.each(sheets, (sheet) ->
      if $(sheet).attr("href")
        $.get($(sheet).attr("href")).then( (data)->
          stylesheet_text += data
        )
    )
    stylesheet_text += "</style>"
    stylesheet_text
```

Just like earlier, the jQuery request doesn't populate the `stylesheet_text` variable like I would expect.

What can I do to ensure that the text is actually appended to the variable before I return at the end of my function?

Comment: Why would you use a jQuery deferred rather than an Angular promise?

Comment: Feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should probably not use jQuery that much in Angular, namely - Angular already ships with deferreds and promises and `$http` can replace `$.get` just fine.

Now for your problem, my CoffeeScript is kind of rusty, but you should chain the promises:

```
ss = ->
    sheets = document.styleSheets
    text = "<script type = 'text/css'>";
    links = sheet.href for sheet in sheets when sheet.href? 
    # now chain them all
    links.reduce((p, c) -> p.then( -> $http.get(c).then(data -> text += data)),$q.when())
         .then(val -> val + "</style>")
```

Now you can do:

```
ss.then(text -> console.log text)
```